# How do you get a part of a json response in python?

Tags: python

I am a new programmer and I'm learning the request module. I'm stuck on the fact that I don't know how to get a specific part of a JSON response. The API just returns JSON:

```
{"status":"success","online":true"}
```

And say I wanted to just get the `"online":true` value.

This is the code I'm currently working with:

```
import requests


def main():
    ask = input("IP : ")
    response = requests.get('https://mcapi.us/server/status?ip=' + ask)
    print(response.content)



main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you have a dictionary with `key` "online"

You need to parse it first with  `.json()` and then you can get it in form `dict[key]`

In your case

```
response = requests.get('https://mcapi.us/server/status?ip=' + ask).json()
print(response["online"])
```

or in case of actual content

```
 response = requests.get('https://mcapi.us/server/status?ip=' + ask).json()
 print(response["content"])
```